# Javascript setTimeout is not working, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, onclick, settimeout

```
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">

<script type="text/javascript">

    function showImage(image) {
        document.getElementById("image").style.visibilty = "visible";
        document.getElementById("image").src = images / GreenLight.jpg;
    }


    function startTimer() {
        var con = confirm("Press a button");
        if (con == true) {
            x = setTimeout(function () { showImage('image') }, 1);
        }
        else {
            x = "You pressed Cancel!";
        }
    }




</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <h1> Page 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="default.htm">Home</a>        </li>
            <li class="here"><a href="page1.htm">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="page2.htm">Page 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <form id="formpage1" method="post" action="default.htm"></form>

        <button onclick="startTimer()">Click Here</button>
        <div>
            <img id="image" src=images/GreenLight.jpg style="visibility:hidden" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">

    </div>
</div>

</body>
 </html>
```

I am trying to get an image to display 5 seconds after the "ok" button is clicked on the alert box. I am so confused as to what i am doing wrong.

Comment: "not working" is the worst issue explanation ever

Comment: *"what am i doing wrong?"* `images / GreenLight.jpg` looks wrong. You probably want `'images/GreenLight.jpg'` (a **string**). Also [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820)

Comment: This: `images / GreenLight.jpg;` There's no `images` variable, the `/` doesn't make sense, and `GreenLight.jpg` is invalid without quotes. You probably meant `"images/GreenLight.jpg"`

Comment: @cookiemonster: It would access the `jpg` property of the `GreenLight` object, which probably doesn't exist ;)

Comment: @FelixKling: Well that's true. :-)

Comment: "5 seconds"? Then why are you passing `1` as the second argument to `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed showImage functions as

```
function showImage(image) {
        document.getElementById(image).style.visibilty = "visible";
        document.getElementById(image).src = "images/GreenLight.jpg";
    }
```

Your HTMLtag of img should be use quotes:

```
<img id="image" src="images/GreenLight.jpg" style="visibility:hidden" />
```

Comment: Are there really spaces in the image path and filename?

Answer (score 2):

You have to form a legal javascript string in this line to get the `.src` property assigned as you wanted.  So change this:

```
document.getElementById("image").src = images / GreenLight.jpg;
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById("image").src = "images/GreenLight.jpg";
```

FYI, the error console would probably have been your friend here as this probably would have been a javascript error and would have given you the error and line number.

---

Your HTML should also use quotes:

```
<img id="image" src="images/GreenLight.jpg" style="visibility:hidden" />
```

---

And, if you want a 5 second delay, then you need to set the time to 5000 milliseconds:

```
setTimeout(function () { showImage('image') }, 5000);
```

Comment: As FelixKling pointed out above, it's not actually invalid code. Just odd and obviously not what the OP desired. `variable / object.property`

Comment: Yes, but that's a ReferenceError. Just saying that it's legal JavaScript and so there won't be a parse error. But +1 since that's clearly what the OP intended.